# Separating RegEx pattern matches that have the same potential starting characters

Tags: python, regex

I would like to have a RegEx that matches several of the same character in a row, within a range of possible characters but does not return those pattern matches as one pattern.  How can this be accomplished?

For clarification:

I want a pattern that starts with [a-c] and ungreedly returns any number of the same character, but not the other characters in the range.  In the sequence 'aafaabbybcccc' it would find patterns for:

('aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'b', 'cccc')

but would exclude the following:

('f', 'aabb', 'y', 'bcccc')

I don't want to use multiple RegEx pattern searches because the order that i find the patterns will determine the output of another function.  This question is for the purposes of self study (python), not homework.  (I'm also under 15 rep but will come back and upvote when I can.)

Comment: I think backreference is a better solution instead of using `|` to match individual chars. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. Use a regex like:

```
(?P<L>[a-c])(?P=L)+
```

This is more robust - you're not limited to a-c, you can replace it with a-z if you like. It first defines any character within a-c as `L`, then sees whether that character occurs again one or more times. You want to run `re.findall()` using this regex.

Comment: I'm actually having trouble getting this to work, but I'm not sure why. test = re.findall('(?P<L>[a-c])(?P=L)+', 'abbracadabbra') -- just returns test as ['b', 'b'] -- is it a python issue?

Comment: Since you want the whole string and not just the repeated letter, you'll have to enclose the whole regex in parentheses. So something like this will work: [t[0] for t in re.findall('((?P<L>[a-c])(?P=L)+)', 'abbracadabbra')]

Comment: Putting the whole thing in parenthesis made it miss the single letter matches, but I think I've got it figured out now. It needed to be ((?P<L>[a-c])(?P=L)*) with an asterisk because otherwise it fails to capture anything that is shorter than the double letter matches.  Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: Oops '*' was greedy, I meant '?'.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize you wanted the single character matches as well. In that case, yes, replacing the `+` with `*` will do it. I thought you wanted to match 2 or more. You're welcome.

Comment: Hmm you do want to be greedy here. '?' will only match 0 or 1 more occurrences ...

Comment: If the string is 'aaaaaabb' I only want it to capture 'aaaaaa' and 'bb' only so I think that ungreedy is the way to go.  If not it will capture 'aaaaaa', 'aaaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaa', 'aa', 'a', 'bb'. 'b'.  Incidentally sorry for flooding the comments I don't have enough rep to chat. :)

Comment: Hmm no .. the line of code I gave you works perfectly with aaaaaabb. findall gives you non-overlapping matches, and you want to match greedily to as far as you can.

Comment: Right you are.  I misunderstood greedy when i read the documentation.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use backreference `\1 - \9` to capture previously matched 1st to 9th group.

```
/([a-c])(\1+)/

[a-c]: Matches one of the character.
\1+  : Matches subsequent one or more previously matched character.
```

Perl:

```
perl -e '@m = "ccccbbb" =~ /([a-c])(\1+)/; print $m[0], $m[1]'

cccc
```

Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> [m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r"([a-c])\1+", 'aafaabbybcccc')]
['aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'cccc']
```

Comment: Interesting.  Is there a good tutorial for how grouping works?

Comment: @Ceryn, [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) has a very good tutorial on regex. [Chapter on grouping and backref](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) gives a good overview of what you want.